# Order By DESC/ASC not working within PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code so far which is within 2 while loops:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listing WHERE 
(category_id='$category' OR category_id_2='$category' OR category_id_3='$category') 
AND listing_status='1' AND listing_type='1' AND listing_id='$listing_id' 
ORDER BY overall DESC");
```

The data is showing exactly what I want, however the ORDER BY simply isn't working. I'm not too sure what it's ordering by. The overall column itself is DECIMAL(12,2).

The values are saved to only 2 decimal places. For instance, in each row it could be 2.56, 2.89. In this case I want the 2.89 to show before the 2.56. However, it's not.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that query in a loop, or do you loop through the results after the query?

Comment: Can you show a sample of the output, running the query from mysql directly? Also, usage of placeholders would be good, using PDO/mysqli.

Comment: An example output is:
1.00
2.82
When I want the 2.82 to be above the 1.00.
Yes there is 1 more while loop above this query to get the "listing_id" from another table. the two }} are after the echo'ing of the 2 numbers above.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and exactly how it's coming out for you with the code above?

Comment: I have added the sample data which is 1.00 and 2.82 and it still outputs the 1.00 before the 2.82 - im simply using echo"$overall"; after the while loop.

Comment: `(category_id='$category' OR category_id_2='$category' OR category_id_3='$category')` ... don't you think you need to have some other table to hold `ListingCategories` ?

Comment: @Ben you should pick an appropriate answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem.

By implementing the 'overall' column in the first loops table, instead of the second. It orders the data first by overall, and then goes ahead and gathers the other data from the second table.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried casting the field as a decimal in the order by?

```
ORDER BY CAST(overall as DECIMAL) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are only selecting one element at a time in your query, something like

```
while(...){
    $category = ...;
    $listing_id = ...;
    // Your query which only returns one result here
}
```

Then since your query only returns one result it has nothing to sort, and you see the results in the order the queries are executed.

You need to rewrite your query to select all the rows you want in one go instead of having it in a loop if you want `ORDER BY` to work. Using `IN` in your query may help you.

Comment: Ha. that would explain this mysterious dummy error. And maybe someone should tell him about sanitizing user input too as I suspect an SQL injection is looking from behind the corner.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM listing WHERE 
    (category_id='$category' OR category_id_2='$category' OR category_id_3='$category') 
    AND listing_status='1' AND listing_type='1' AND listing_id='$listing_id' 
    ORDER BY overall+0 DESC");
```

Comment: Even using ASC or DESC doesn't have any effect on the how the numbers are listed.

Comment: I've tried *,+,-,/ and with/without brackets, still doesn't change the output? How strange.

Comment: `overall*0` would just be `ORDER BY 0`. Not particularly useful.

Comment: `ORDER BY CAST(overall*10 as INT) DESC`

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem.

By implementing the 'overall' column in the first loops table, instead of the second. It orders the data first by overall, and then goes ahead and gathers the other data from the second table.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The query is fine. The problem is probably with how you iterate returned data. Try changing it.
If not, provide us with the whole relevant piece of your PHP code.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but I found out by copying and pasting from phpmyadmin that this worked to solve a similar problem.  The ' is changed to ` - dunno if it's important.  But definitely `ASC` worked with the second way.

Important - the have been stripped from the second method, put them around the table name and the column names.

instead of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM 'dczcats' ORDER BY 'first' , 'second' ASC";
```

I typed this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `dczcats` ORDER BY `dczcats`.`first` , `dczcats`.`second` ASC";
```